# Multiple databases in one project - Entity framework (self tracking entities)

Tags: entity-framework

In my project, I want to have access to 2 different databases. I created two .edmx files in the same project, added the self tracking entities T4 thingie, and kaboom :) Does not work anymore.

I get a looooooot of ambiguity errors (ObjectChangeTracker and such)

What would be the preferred solution here? I can delete the duplicate content in the generated files but when modifying the .edmx file it just regenerates of course... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Providing none of your database objects are named the same, you can comment out part of the T4 template which creates generic objects for one copy of your edmx file.

```
WriteHeader(fileManager);
BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
/* Comment out this part
WriteObjectChangeTracker();
WriteIObjectWithChangeTracker();
WriteCustomObservableCollection();
WriteINotifyComplexPropertyChanging();
WriteEqualityComparer();
*/
EndNamespace(namespaceName);
```

If you do have database objects named the same, I'd recommend putting each edmx file in a separate namespace.